# Международный домен

Tags: домен

Чем международный домен лучше? Допустим .com чем .ru
Знакомый говорил что это связанно с законом или что-то в этом роде, не поясните?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласен с [[@ViruSkin](/users/8641/viruskin)](/users/8641/viruskin), но хотелось бы описать подробнее.

По российскому законодательству, делегирование домена может приостановить записка из полиции. Но это если домен российский, хостинг российский и т.д. То есть, если физическое расположение сервера - Роисся. Если же нет - сервер за границей - то для приостановки необходимо, как минимум, решение суда. Да и международные власти не всегда идут на это. Тем более владельцы сервера.

---

*К тому же, хотя я честно признаюсь - не уверен на все 100%, заграничные власти могут отказать в приостановке, если контент не противоречит **их законодательству.***

Answer (score 1):

ФСБ рукой не дотянется, т.е. труднее захватить домен. Как пример проект **путин взрывает дома**, ФСБ приостановило их домены в зоне .рф, но не сумели закрыть [putinvzrivaetdoma.org](http://putinvzrivaetdoma.org)

Comment: А с .me тоже самое?